# Pause execution in Java GUI

Tags: java, android, user-interface, sleep

I am writing a quiz program for the Android (written in Java). When the user answers a question (by clicking a button), I want to flash a message on the screen saying whether they were correct or not, followed by a 5 second pause before moving on to the next question.

However, when an answer button is clicked, the program pauses, but does not display the message of correct/incorrect. The message only comes up once the sleep method has finished.

```
if (correct)   
    Answer.setText("CORRECT!"); 
else 
    Answer.setText("WRONG!"); 

try { Thread.sleep(5000); } 
catch(InterruptedException e) {}
```

As a bonus, I'd like the answer buttons to be disabled during the pause.

Comment: Are you really sure a Thread.sleep is a good idea? Besides, having it 5 seconds means that if you're just slightly slower then the Android not answering dialog might pop up. If you absolutely have to make it sleep, make it sleep for a shorter while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imo `AsyncTask` is too much for this usecase.

Don't use sleep.
Instead set your correct/incorrect message and than do this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
  public void run()
  {
    goToNextScreen();
  }
}
, 5000);
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that.  Google gives you an intro to it [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

When you Thread.sleep() on the main Activity, you are putting the application to sleep.  The AsyncTask will allow you to pause for the 5 seconds, maybe show a little In Progress bar and then pick up from there, without freezing the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html): you can send a message with a 5000 millisecond delay, disable the buttons and when the message arrives you can re-enable the buttons. See https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html for more info.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into using timers for this. I don't think using threads are sensible for this. Using a timer to move onto the next question would work.

Look at [timers here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I have only used timers in Java to do something similar but i'm sure it would work in Android.

Comment: What's strange to me is that I have tried using timers, and I still have the same issue. I don't have a strong understanding of threads and how they're used with GUI's, but there must be a simple fix.